# Filter a users contact list of people of known phone numbers using ABAddressBook

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

For whatever reason I can't find this anywhere, but I am coding an iphone app and am trying to
filter a users contact list of people of known phone numbers using the `ABAddressBook` framework.

I want the contacts list, which is a `UITableViewController`, to be split up into 2 sections: contacts already on the app, and contacts not on the app. I have the contacts list stored in an NSArray and I need to figure out how to determine whether or not the contact in the array is in the app already or not.

Once this is done, I need to be able to add contacts from the already using the app section to a 'friends list' `UITableViewController`.

Thank you so much!

Here's my .m file code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.contacts = [[NSArray alloc]init];
[self getAllContacts];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

//GETS RID OF WEIRD OVERLAP BUG ON TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER
[self.navigationController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return self.contacts.count;
}

-(void)getAllContacts
{
APAddressBook *addressBook = [[APAddressBook alloc]init];
addressBook.fieldsMask = APContactFieldAll;
addressBook.filterBlock = ^BOOL(APContact *contact){
    return (contact.phones.count > 0) && !(contact.firstName == nil && contact.lastName     == nil);
};

[addressBook loadContacts:^(NSArray *apContacts, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        for (APContact *AP in apContacts) {
            Contact *contact = [Contact new];
            contact.firstName = AP.firstName?[AP.firstName stringByAppendingString:@"   "]:@"";
            contact.lastName = AP.lastName?AP.lastName:@" ";
            contact.fullName = [contact.firstName   stringByAppendingString:contact.lastName];
            if(AP.emails && [AP.emails count] > 0) {
                contact.email = [AP.emails firstObject]?:nil;
            }

            if(AP.thumbnail ) {
                contact.image = AP.thumbnail;
            } else {
              /*  contact.image = [UIImage imageNamed:]; ADD GENERIC DEFAULT IMAGE*/
            }
            if(AP.phones && [AP.phones count] > 0) {
                NSString *phone = [AP.phones firstObject];
                contact.phoneNumber = [NSString formatNumber:phone];
                contact.numberToDisplay = phone;
                contact.identifier = [NSString formatNumber:phone];
            } /*else {
                contact.identifier = [AP.emails firstObject];

        }*/
            [dic setValue:contact forKey:contact.fullName];
        }

        self.contacts = [dic allValues];

        [self setupContacts];

    } else {
        //write an alert error.description
    }


 }];

}

-(void)setupContacts{

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"fullName"   ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
self.contacts = [self.contacts sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

if (!self.selectedContacts) {
    self.selectedContacts = [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc]initWithCapacity:self.contacts.count];
}
self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;

 [self.tableView reloadData];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ContactsCell";
ContactsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (ContactsCell *)[[ContactsCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
Contact *contact = [self.contacts objectAtIndex:row];
cell.mainTextLabel.text = contact.fullName;

cell.hidden = NO;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: This question is extremely vague. What you're describing requires a backend service to store user's contact information to compare against.